# Is this iOS application a Web Application?

Tags: php, ios, web

I'm developing an iOS application that communicates with my server.

[image]
Above picture shows how my iOS works.

I want to know whether my iOS application is an Web Application or not and
what is Web Application exactly.

I read this website: https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/web-application/.

However the definition of Web Application is too ambiguous to me.
It seems that usually web browsers are needed for Web Application to perform tasks.

However my iOS application doesn't need web browsers(chrome, safari etc..) to perform tasks and my iOS application is essential to perform tasks.

I have some questions:

1. In this case, is my iOS application(including php Server and db) a Web Application?
2. Is my php Server including db a Web Application?
3. Is my iOS application a web browser? (My application is quite different from web browsers such as Chrome and Safari, as it only communicates with my php server and it doesn't show web page. My app just ueses json http response from server to perform tasks)

Comment: Without internet, would your app work? The answer would answer your question.

Comment: No. My app doesn't work without the Internet. The internet connection is essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is classed as a "Native app" and not a "Web application", even though it relies on a web service in the back end.  Almost all useful native apps rely on some back end service and this is generally always a web service like yours is.

The term "Web Application" is generally used to refer to an application that is accessed directly by the user via a web browser and which renders a user interface using HTML.

To answer your other question: Your native app is not a web browser (* however, see note below).  The term "Web browser" is reserved for an application that is specifically designed to browse websites that have a web (HTML) front end.  You have a native front end.  That is, your user interface is rendered using the device's native controls.

Note: To add confusion to the matter you can in fact embed a web browser into your native app so that it contains web browser functionality.  In that case you would say you have a "Native app with embedded web browser".

Lastly, a native app can in fact **be** a web browser (like Safari for example) however I doubt you're building a web browser unless you're trying to compete with Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. and.. how about my php server? Can my php server be classed as a web application? It doesn't work properly in web browsers.

Comment: "Web application" is generally used to refer to an application that is accessed directly by the user via a web browser and which renders a user interface using HTML.  Your back end is classed as a "Web service" - That term implies that it's an application hosted on the Web for the purpose of serving other apps (ie: your iOS native app)

Comment: I got it! Thank you again. You are genius. :-)